# Rotating image with ImageTK(PIL) get cropped

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am loading an image using these two functions:

```
# Function that browse image
def browse_image():
    global image_object, image_loaded_label
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select An Image",
                                               filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpeg"),("png files", "*.png")))
    openimage(root.filename)
    listbox.delete(0, 'end')


# Function that opens image loaded
def openimage(uri):
    global image_object

    image = Image.open(uri)
    image_object = image.resize((450, 350), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image_loaded = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_object)
    img_lbl.configure(image=image_loaded)
    img_lbl.image = image_loaded
```

then I rotate the image:

```
# Rotating image left and right
def rotate_image(direction):
    global image_object
    angle = {"left": 90, "right": -90}[direction]
    image_object = image_object.rotate(angle)
    rotated_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_object)
    img_lbl.config(image=rotated_tk)
    img_lbl.image = rotated_tk
```

But after the rotation it gets cropped and I can't understand why, is there something I'm doing wrong? I put pictures to show how it gets cropped
Is there a way to not crop it, or crop it at the loading?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the image has width and height properties who are different. So that should be the reason why the image gets cropped.

So the picture should be a "perfect" square.

Comment: You mean that I should not resize it with image.resize((450, 350)?

Comment: If you want so, but make sure to set the width and height to be the same